Ticket office vs. ticketing office
what's the difference in meaning between ticket office and ticketing office? Thank you ~
"Ticket office"
"Ticketing Office"

Ticket office is much more common than ticketing office - except, apparently, in Malaysia and The Philippines. To my (British) ear, ticketing office sounds wrong, as if it had been said or written by a non-native speaker.
The GloWBe corpus has 851 instances of ticket office against 87 for ticketing office (9.8:1); but 47 of those 87 are in Malaysian and Filipino sources. If you leave out those two countries, the numbers are 797 : 40 (19.9:1)
Box office is far more common than either, (8209:851:87 in GloWBe), but as somebody pointed out in an edit, that is only used for entertainment, and not normally for transport.
Other corpora have an even greater disparity: the NOW corpus has 5926 against 284 (20.9:1) and iWeb 15486:178 (87:1)!
Edit: Corrected "Singapore" to "Phillipines", as I misread the columns in the corpus output. Made a number of other edits, including about box office. Made further edit to remove "established phrase" after comment from Astralbee.

In the context of movies, concerts, shows, etc., we might see "box office" often, though this doesn't apply e.g. to train tickets

They have 'ticketing offices' in Hong Kong, Indonesia, and the Phillipines, so I guess it may be an East/Southeast Asia regional variation, and I have seen it in what are probably non-professionally-written UK web items about e.g. tennis clubs.

I've corrected "Singapore" to "Philippines" in my answer, and also introduced _box office).

The top hit in the Google book search in my answer turns up a 2017 US English book that refers to "ticketing" offices, in connection with theatres, in the midwest. It's not an isolated example, either. So while I agree that "ticket office" is by far the most common I think this answer is misleading as its main focus is 'proving' that it is not "an established phrase". Another 2+2=5 answer.

@Astralbee: edited accordingly.

There is literally no difference in meaning.
'Ticket' can be a noun and a verb. To ticket means to issue a ticket.
Compound nouns can be created by stringing nouns together (like "ticket office") or using adjectives, verbs (especially -ing verbs) to add detail to the main noun. So "ticket office" and "ticketing office" are just two ways of referring to the same thing.
As an example, the place where you can leave your vehicle in British English is a "car park" (noun+noun), but the same thing in American English is a "parking lot" (verb+noun). Again, two ways to describe the same thing.
Of the two, "ticket office" is certainly the idiomatic one that most native speakers use. However, this search of Google Books shows that "ticketing office" is sometimes used, and we'd certainly understand it.

Oxford Languages via Google:
verb
gerund or present participle: ticketing



issue (someone) with an official notice of a traffic offense.
"park illegally and you are likely to be ticketed"


2.(of a passenger) be issued with a travel ticket.
"passengers can now get electronically ticketed"


ticket office for methods of transportation, where you buy tickets, or entertainment aka for that second one box office where you buy tickets for plays or shows (films). Also, a place where tickets are issued for various offences.
ticketing services, a service offered by a company or organization
Here are the Harvard box office and ticketing services. For entertainment.
ticketing system or software: programs for managing ticket sales
Generally, in the West we don't use ticketing office for entertainment or travel tickets, but could slip up and say it.

Exactly. In the West, it's a non-standard 'slip-up'.

@MichaelHarvey Thank you. I got two dvs anyway. I simpl don't get the folks around here. :) And I think I hit all the main points.
